# How to update multiple tables in hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I am having mySql query and need to transfer it in to hibernate query. I have transferred simple queries into hibernate. But its difficult for me to convert "UPDATE" query. Below is the MySql query,

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("UPDATE  bus_transport.trip_calendar a ,");
query.append("bus_transport.trip_resource_allocator b,");
query.append("bus_transport.vehicle_calendar c ,");
query.append("bus_transport.driver_calendar d ");

query.append("SET c.vehicle_status_code='Available',");
query.append("a.route_code='" + jsonObjInside.getString("rCode") + "',");
query.append("a.trip_from_date_time='" + finalStartDateTime + "',");
query.append("a.trip_to_date_time='" + finalEndDateTime + "',");
query.append("b.emp_id='" + jsonObjInside.getString("driverId") + "' ,");
query.append("b.vehicle_id='" + jsonObjInside.getString("vehId") + "',");
query.append("c.vehicle_id='" + jsonObjInside.getString("vehId")+ "' ,");
query.append("d.emp_id='" + jsonObjInside.getString("driverId") + "'");

query.append("where a.trip_id='" + jsonObjInside.getString("tripId")+ "'");
query.append(" and b.trip_id='" + jsonObjInside.getString("tripId") + "'");
query.append("and c.trip_id='" + jsonObjInside.getString("tripId")+ "'");
query.append("and d.trip_id='" + jsonObjInside.getString("tripId")+ "' ");

int var = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

Please help me to convert into Hibernate Update query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can achieve this update procedure by multiple `update` statement, in the meantime, you need to ensure these update statement are in one transaction!

Answer (score 6):

Converting an update statement to HQL would be very similar to converting any SQL statement to HQL. Assuming you have your object mapping set-up correctly already you'd just need to write a correct HQL QUERY. You'll need to use the HQL([HQL Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html)) syntax. You replace the table & column names with the object names you have set up.

This:

```
UPDATE  bus_transport.trip_calendar a , bus_transport.trip_resource_allocator b,
bus_transport.vehicle_calendar c , bus_transport.driver_calendar d "
```

could be come something like this:

```
UPDATE  TripCalendar a , TripResourceAllocator b,
VehicleCalendar c , DriverCalendar d "
```

You reference columns in a similar fashion

This:

```
SET c.vehicle_status_code='Available'
```

Could become something like this:

```
SET c.vehicleStatusCode = 'Available'
```

For more on the Hiberate DML specific stuff check out this link: [HQL DML Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/batch.html#batch-direct)

Comment: Listing multiple entities after the UPDATE is actually not possible.

Comment: You cannot list multiple tables in UPDATE of hibernate. you need to use something else