# JDBC UPDATE query into HQL

Tags: hibernate, jdbc, hql

How can I write the following JDBC MySQL query into HQL?

```
"UPDATE app a, sec s SET a.Name=?, a.Surname=?, a.DOB=?, s.Email1=?, s.Email2=? WHERE (a.rid=? && s.rid=?)";
```

Comment: So many details are missing from your question, including the class definitions.  Can you update?

Comment: This is my old JDBC Query which I have trimmed for readability purpose. I am migrating my project to hibernate.

So, there is a form to update the records the classes which are concerned in the above query are POJO classes Applicant that maps to app table and Class SecDTO that maps to sec table in mysql and I am trying to write HQL query in Test class. 

The above query I was using in JDBC where rid is the primary key in app table and it is a foreign key in the sec table.

Comment: This links seems to have a similar requirement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943047/how-to-update-multiple-tables-in-hibernate but according to the comments in answer seems like its not possible in hibernate to update specific columns of multiple table using HQL.